# why webpack's tree shaking mechanism not working when we use mode as "development"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Webpack version: 5+

In my current project, I am trying to remove the unwanted and unused exports from my code while bundling my code using the tree-shaking technique with the mode "development" and has output libraryTarget as "commonjs2". But still, my code does not reduce its bundle size. How can I fix this issue?

This is my webpack config file and I am using typescript.

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer' // used this to analyse my bundle size
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin"

const conf = {
  // includeModules: true,
  prodMode: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
};


/**
 * Webpack Config
 */
const webpackConfig = {
  entry: "/coder/nodejs/index.ts",
  target: "node",
  mode: conf.prodMode ? "production" : "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".tsx"],
  },
  optimization:{
    providedExports: true,
    usedExports: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin()
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: resolve(__dirname, "./coder/nodejs/dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "[absolute-resource-path]",
  },
  devtool: "cheap-source-map",
  plugins: [
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ]
};

export default webpackConfig;
```